# Setting a variable back to zero

Tags: java

I'm teaching myself Java using one of the ebooks on Amazon. I was doing one of the lessons which does a "benchmark" of the computer. It does this by looping for a minute and calculating the results.

It basically doesn't show you anything for a minute until it's done. So my was making a small modification to show a dot as a progress bar of sorts every few seconds. Normally this is a trivial thing,  but something's not right, and I don't know what.

What happens is miniIndex will reach the threshold I specified, and print the value of miniIndex and a period. Its then supposed to set miniIndex to zero so that counter can restart. But it doesn't reset, and never increments again. It's very odd behavior.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
class Benchmark {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + 60000;
        long index = 0;

        // My inner index
        int miniIndex = 0;
        //
        while (true) {
            double x = Math.sqrt(index);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now > endTime){
                break;
            }
            index++;
            // my modification
            miniIndex++;
            if (miniIndex >= 5000) {
                System.out.print(miniIndex + ".");
                miniIndex = 0;
            }
            // end of my modification
        }
        System.out.println(index + " loops in one minute.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine, it will print the dot. Recompile your code and retest it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using netbeans to run it real-time. When I run it, the miniIndex reaches 5000, and then prints the miniIndex value and the period with each iteration of the while loop, instead of every 5000 miliseconds.

Comment: Why would it print every 5000 milliseconds?  You aren't comparing it to time at all

Comment: Unrelated but really odd. When I posted this, my opening sentence was "Hello All, first post here". The system stripped out "Hello All,", even after trying to edit and put it back in.

Comment: @SteelRat It doesn't print the miniIndex and the dot at every iteration of the while loop, only at every 5000th, because it is programmed liked that.

Comment: @SteelRat See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251077/my-opening-hi-everyone-in-my-question-keeps-disappearing for your "Hello All" removed thing.

Comment: You're not showing a dot "every few seconds" - you're showing a dot every 5000 iterations, which can and will spam the output on a fast system.

Comment: @Nexevis - I am, sort of. The main loop counts milliseconds, or is supposed to, and quit when the end value of 60000 is reached.

Comment: @SteelRat The main loop doesn't count milliseconds either. You are just doing `index++` and `miniIndex++` in a `while` loop.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I wasn't realizing what the main loop was really counting. So my 5000 was supposed to be every few seconds, but it's way faster than that.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I wasn't fully understanding what was being compared. So it was a loose nut behind the keyboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what your `miniIndex++` operation is doing, as it is not counting milliseconds but instead is counting the number of loop iterations which are *not* equal to each other.  I have modified your code to execute the `if` statement inside every 5 seconds, according to what you wanted to happen:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long miniTime = startTime; //Declare miniTime equal to startTime
    long endTime = startTime + 60000;
    long index = 0;

    while (true) {
        double x = Math.sqrt(index);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now > endTime){
            break;
        }
        index++;

        // my modification    
        //Current time minus last time the if executed and check if 5 seconds passed
        if ((now - miniTime) >= 5000) { 
            miniTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("5 seconds have passed.");

            //if you want to print the actual time elapsed every 5 seconds use this print
            //System.out.println((now - startTime)/1000 + " seconds have passed.");
        }
        // end of my modification
    }
    System.out.println(index + " loops in one minute.");
}
```

Notice how I now compare current time of `now` and subtract the `miniTime` to check to see if it is higher than or equal 5000 milliseconds.  To use time you *must* relate it to time somehow, in this case `System.currentTimeMillis()` and the results.  Numbers themselves such as counting the loop will never be time consistent.

A loop may execute millions of times, but only take 3 seconds.

**Example Output:**

```
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
5 seconds have passed.
16319642816 loops in one minute.
```

**Note:** `5 seconds have passed.` prints 11 times because at the 60 second mark the loop is broken so the final pass is not printed.  (And `11 * 5` is 55 for the first 55 seconds).

Comment: @Steel Rat Scratch my last comment about counting time with integer,  I added a better way to do it as a comment (printing `now - start`)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working fine; it's your expectations that are flawed.

Your code prints a dot every 5,000 iterations. Which is going to basically spew values. Remember, your CPU is running at something > 2 billion operations a second. You can probably do a few million of those loops per second. Call it a million loops per second, divided by 5000 is 200 dots per second, more or less, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to use it in that type of output you can make it easier using `StringBuilder`. It's coded like that:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

and incide the loop like that:

```
if (miniIndex >= 5000) {
    stringBuilder.append(miniIndex).append(".");
    miniIndex = 0;
}

if (stringBuilder.length() >= 200) {
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
    stringBuilder.setLength(0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to stay within my level of knowledge (which is obviously pretty low). I was just confused as to why the miniIndex wasn't resetting or incrementing any more. As you guys have pointed out, both things were happening, just orders of magnitude faster than I was expecting.

Comment: Challenges and results are the part of programming that makes people happy.
If would be interested in benchmarks I would recommend you to meet threads, formatting and I/O so it could make your learning faster.

Comment: but why wait until the length is 200 to print?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger it's all up for developer. You can specify that length of string that you want to appear in each line. Console buffers have different size and buffer size so it could be efficient.
So each time `StringBuffer` string contains 200 chars it would print it.

Comment: but why? OP just wants a sign of life every so often, no need to create a string with 200 chars (or any other length), actually just one dot would suffice ("*show a dot as a progress bar of sorts every few seconds*")

Comment: So probably there are more efficient ways to indicate the progress.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably overwhelming your output or something, such that it doesn't print anything at all. Your loop waits until 60000 milliseconds (1 minute). When I ran it, [here](https://pastebin.com/eS58U1by) was the end part of my output. Since your loop iterates very very fast (as fast as the computer can print, because that is the bottleneck here), NOT one iteration per second/millisecond, your counter `miniIndex` goes up many many times per second. However, your code does work - it just doesn't do what you think it does.

If you try something like the following, you may get a slightly more precise output:

```
class Benchmark {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + 60000;
        long index = 0;

        // My inner index
        int miniIndex = 0;
        //
        while (true) {
            double x = Math.sqrt(index);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now > endTime){
                break;
            }
            index++;
            // my modification
            miniIndex++;
            if (miniIndex >= 5000) {
                System.out.print(miniIndex + ".");
                miniIndex = 0;
            }
            // end of my modification
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(index + " loops in one minute.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ..........50976 loops in one minute.

Notice that you may not get 60,000 loops a minute, as Thread.sleep(1) can sleep for slightly over 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

To see why it didn't work, you need to print the variable "**now**" while looping. You will notice that "**now**" stays the same for a certain amount while in the loop and eventually it will increment by one. So when you have one thousand of those increments it equates to a period of 1 sec. What the variable "**miniIndex**" is doing is counting up to 5000 loops and then resets, nowadays computers can perform thousands and thousands of loops in a second. Which is why it seemed like it wasn't resetting.

You can change the wait variable in the code to show different dot progress like you wanted.

```
    class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {


            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long endTime = startTime + 60000;
            long index = 0;

            long wait  = 5000; //secs  5000 == 5sec

            long secondsPassed = startTime + wait; 

            System.out.print("counting");
            while (true) {
                double x = Math.sqrt(index);
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (now > endTime){
                    break;
                }
                index++;

                if (now >= secondsPassed) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                    secondsPassed = secondsPassed + wait;
                }


            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(index + " loops in one minute.");
      }
    }
```